# Why does SignalR work only with form elements?

Tags: javascript, angular, signalr

I am using signalR in my angular application. The following is the code

```
// Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
  $.connection.hub.url = 'https://www.url../signalr';
  var response = $.connection.responseHub;
  // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
  response.client.broadcastResponses = function (responses) {
    $('#time').val(new Date().toLocaleString());
    var obj = JSON.parse(responses);
    var length = Object.keys(obj).length;
    console.log(length);
   //$('#length').val(Object.keys(obj).length);
  };
  $.connection.hub.start();
```

Now I am trying to display the time and the length of the response. They are displayed correctly in the console, but get displayed only wen I use 
`<input type="text" id="time"/>`
and
`<input type="text" id="length"/>`

But I don't want to display it as an input field. I want to use tags such as `<h5>` or `<p>` to display the information.

Why does only the form fields work for this?

How can I work around this to get what I want?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously we're mixing jQuery into your angular front end, but the jQuery to set an `h5` would be `$('h3').text('someValue')` (and not `val()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `SignalR`.

For `h` and `p` elements use `html()` or `text()` functions and not `val()`. `val()` only works for input elements.

`$('#p_id').html(Object.keys(obj).length);`

Comment: Thanks! Thank you for clarifying my doubt.